# SQL Group by with return boolean for any

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to do a group by and return a boolean for whether the group by contains a value in the group.

I have two Tables Title Table and Items Table.

The Title.ID is a foreign key to my Items Table.

My Items Table has a multiple format codes and I need to Select A Boolean if a group contains a format code

The Sql Statement look like:

```
 Select t.ID, Any(i.Formatcode = 'DOD') as hasDODItem
 From Title t
 join Item i on i.TitleID = t.ID
 group by t.ID.
```

I'm looking for a function that would be like Any(i.Formatcode = 'DOD') as hasDODItem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select t.ID, max(case when i.Formatcode = 'DOD' then 1 else 0) as hasDODItem
from Title as t
    inner join Item as i on i.TitleID = t.ID
group by t.ID
```

or you can do this with subquery and `exists`:

```
select
    t.ID,
    case
        when exists (
            select *
            from Item as i
            where i.TitleID = t.ID and i.Formatcode = 'DOD'
        ) then 1
        else 0
    end as hasDODItem
from Title as t
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `case`:

```
 Select t.ID, (case when i.Formatcode = 'DOD' then 1 else 0 end) as hasDODItem
 From Title t join
      Item i
      on i.TitleID = t.ID
 group by t.ID
```

EDIT:

If you just want to know ids that have a particular item, then use `exists` rather than a `join`:

```
 Select t.ID,
        (case when exists (select 1
                           from item i
                           where i.TitleID = t.ID and i.Formatcode = 'DOD' 
                          )
              then 1 else 0 end) as hasDODItem
 From Title t ;
```

The `join` is not necessary.  I thought you wanted it for some reason.

Comment: won't I have to some how include the i.formatcode which will then return multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use EXISTS to find out if Formatcode = 'DOD' is there:

```
select t.ID, case when exists (select 1 from Item i
                               where i.Formatcode = 'DOD'
                               and i.TitleID = t.ID) then true else false end
from Title t
```